# How To Get Snowflake Stored Procedure DDL with $$

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We prefer coding Snowflake stored procedures and javascript UDF's using the $$ notation. It is easier as we do not have to worry about escaping every single quote in our code.  However, when we retrieve the DDL using GET_DDL, Snowflake removes the $$ and places the body of the SP in single quotes and also escapes every single quote.

Is there a way to get the SP DDL from Snowflake in the $$ format?

Example, below is the SP we create.  Notice the $$ sign and that we do not hae

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_TEST"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
    var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: "select 'Hello World!' as test;"})
    result.next();
    return String(result.getColumnValue(1));
$$;
```

Then, when we retrieve the DDL from Snowflake using SELECT GET_DDL('PROCEDURE','SP_TEST()'), we get the following.  Notice the $$ has been replaced by single quotes and that all other single quotes are now escaped.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_TEST"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS '


    var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: "select ''Hello World!'' as test;"})
    result.next();
    return String(result.getColumnValue(1));
';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've not found a built-in way to do it, but you can use a UDF to do this. This should work provided that the $$ start and end of the code section are always on lines by themselves:

```
create or replace function CODE_DDL_TO_TEXT(CODE_TEXT string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    var lines = CODE_TEXT.split("\n");
    var out = "";
    var startCode = new RegExp("^AS '$", "ig");
    var endCode = new RegExp("^'\;$", "ig");
    var inCode = false;
    var isChange = false;
    var s;
    for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        isChange = false;
        if(!inCode) {
            inCode = startCode.test(lines[i]);
            if(inCode) {
                isChange = true;
                out += "AS $" + "$\n";
            }
        }
        if (endCode.test(lines[i])){
            out += "$" + "$;";
            isChange = true;
            inCode = false;
        }
        if(!isChange){
            if(inCode){
                s = lines[i].replace(/''/g, "'") + "\n";
                s = s.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
                out += s;
            } else {
                out += lines[i] + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
$$;

select CODE_DDL_TO_TEXT(get_ddl('function', 'CODE_DDL_TO_TEXT(string)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
execute immediate $$
DECLARE
   PROCS RESULTSET;
   ALL_PROCS RESULTSET;
   DB_NAME STRING DEFAULT 'PROC_TEST';
   TABLE_NAME   STRING;
   QUERY        STRING;
   ALL_QUERY    STRING;
   COUNT INT DEFAULT 0;
   OUTPUT       STRING DEFAULT '';
   c1           CURSOR FOR select DATABASE_NAME from snowflake.information_schema.databases;
BEGIN
   TABLE_NAME := CONCAT(DB_NAME, '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA');
   OPEN c1;

   FOR rec IN c1 DO
       QUERY := 'SELECT PROCEDURE_CATALOG,PROCEDURE_NAME,PROCEDURE_OWNER,PROCEDURE_DEFINITION FROM ' || rec.DATABASE_NAME || '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.procedures';
       OUTPUT := OUTPUT || QUERY || '\n UNION ALL \n';
       --PROCS := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY);
       -- ALL_PROCS := ALL_PROCS + PROCS;
   END FOR;
   --ALL_PROCS := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :OUTPUT);
   --RETURN table(ALL_PROCS);
   RETURN OUTPUT;

END;
$$;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).