# Snowflake Missing Definition By DDL Command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a user and a role.

I granted privileges to database , schema and a warehouse . Also granted for schemas which have procedures.

But when I try to get procedure ddl by select get_ddl command it is giving like.

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "EMPLOYEE_INSERT"() RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216) LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT EXECUTE AS OWNER AS '';`

I am not getting procedure definition . It would be happy if I get any help .Thanks.

Comment: If you run get_ddl as ACCOUNTADMIN does it show the full ddl? What privileges does the role you are using have on the schema where the SP exists?

Comment: yeah i am getting full ddl with ACCOUNTADMIN , role has access on schema and also procedures too.                                                                                                                  
GRANT USAGE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA admin.query_monitoring TO ROLE custom;
Also granted role to schema.

Comment: Here i am using new user also named user1 i granted role to this user also .

Comment: There is no such privilege as “access”. Please provide the all actual privileges the role has on the database, schema and SP

Comment: GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA db1.schema1 TO ROLE role1;

GRANT USAGE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA db1.schema1 TO ROLE role1;

i used these two commands and also grant permission to db and schema to role.

But still not getting through coding and also in snowflake .

Comment: I think this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/65258226/245915. Snowflake recently addressed this. Please see my latest answer in that question.

Answer (score 0):

Since `get_ddl` is returning anything at all, chances are the role in context has the required grants. The most likely reason you're seeing this is because it's returning an overload of the stored procedure -- probably an older one where someone created just a stub with no body and no parameters.

Run `show procedures in schema` or if the one you need doesn't show up you can go up a level and `show procedures in database`.

In the return, check the "arguments" column. When you run `select get_ddl('procedure'...` make sure to specify the arguments for the overload of interest.

For example, you may see something like this in the "arguments" column:

`FOO(VARCHAR, VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR`

In that case, to get the body of the SP you would run:

`select get_ddl('procedure', 'FOO(VARCHAR, VARCHAR)');`

One final thought on this one: get_ddl will return the body of the SP with the AS section wrapped in single quotes. That means it has to double the single quotes everywhere in the body of the SP. If the original create statement is not available, this makes modifying the code retrieving it from get_ddl more difficult. I wrote a stored procedure for an answer here to change to $$ for the wrappers and single ticks:  [How To Get Snowflake Stored Procedure DDL with $$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273734/how-to-get-snowflake-stored-procedure-ddl-with/62274188#62274188)

Comment: Thank you . But I used the same process to get procedures .  I am not getting by using coding and in snowflake ui also . I mentioned arguments correctly . After AS in between single quotes i am not getting procedure definition .

Comment: `I am not getting by using coding and in snowflake ui also .` I'm not sure I understand, but are you trying to get the procedures to display in the object explorer window on the left side of the Snowflake UI?

Comment: No , coding means through java code by jdbc connection .